# Why ionic Network Plugin is not working after upgrading.?

Tags: plugins, ionic2

This code was working fine till upgrade to `ionic 3.4`.

now in serve command shows :

> **Property 'connection' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.**

I've replaced this code `Network.connection` with `navigator.connection` but still the same result.

```
export class NetworkService {

 onDevice: boolean;

  constructor(public platform: Platform , private Network: Network){
    this.onDevice = this.platform.is('cordova');
  }

  isOnline(): boolean {
    if(this.onDevice && Network.connection){
      return Network.connection !== Connection.NONE;
    } else {
      return navigator.onLine; 
    }
  }

  isOffline(): boolean {
    if(this.onDevice && Network.connection){
      return Network.connection === Connection.NONE;
    } else {
      return !navigator.onLine;   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi - please check the tag descriptions before you add them.  I get an automatic email for each networkx-tagged question.  I then come and read the question.  Networkx is a python package that has nothing to do with network configurations in computers.  Your question has nothing to do with python, and is all about network configurations.

Comment: @joeI am not familiar with python it is about ionic.

Comment: My point is, you added a 'networkx' tag whose description explicitly says it's for a specific python package (which you are not using).  All I'm asking is that in the future you check that description for any tag before using it

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper around that plugin has changed and doesn't expose a 'connection' property. Instead you need to use 'type' property. Full example available on the ionic documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/).